# Hierarchical Data - Nested Set Model: MySql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I am just learning how to implement the Nested Set Model but still have confusion with a certain aspect of it involving items that may be part of multiple categories.  Given the example below that was pulled from [**HERE**](http://articles.sitepoint.com/print/hierarchical-data-database) and mirrors many other examples I have come across...

[image: Hierarchical Data: Numbered Tree]

[image: Table]

How do you avoid duplication in the DB when you add Apples since they are multi-colored (i.e. Red, Yellow, Green)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not avoid duplications and the apple (or a reference to the apple) will be placed twice in your tree otherwise it won't be a tree but rather a graph. Your question is equally applicable if you build a... Swing JTree or an HTML tree ;).

The nested set model is just an efficient way to push and traverse a tree structure in a relational DB.It is not a data structure itself. It's more popular among MySQL users since MySQL lacks functionality for processing tree structures (e.g. like the one that Oracle provides).

Cheers!

Comment: Yeah I have been searching for an answer but can not find anything definitive on the subject. I am using MySQL at this point so will I run into problems converting to a non-free DB in the future with the duplication of Apple? Or should I try and resolve this issue by not allowing multiple parents at this point and just use the Nested Set approach as it stands? Or is there another way to tackle this issue utilizing MySQL?

Comment: At least in the context of Oracle you will not run into any problems. The nested set approach is pretty portable because it uses standard SQL constructs. In the general context I see no evil with the duplication of the apple _reference_. I never used the nested sets in my practice though I'm familiar with it. But I would be more concerned about the modifications (add/delete/move of nodes) of the tree. They are generally slower. Also note that this is not a standard technique and maintainers of your solution may need a difficult start.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this problem.  If you have the chance and are willing can you please look at my follow on question to this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5395463/data-modeling-modeling-categories-subcategories-in-mysql

Answer (score 4):

Nested set model is a structure for 1:N (one-to-many) relationships, you want to use M:N (many to many) relationship (many items can have apple as parent, but can have more than one parent).

[See this article](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/many-to-many.html&ei=eO2FTeinL4XMsgbMkJiLAw&usg=AFQjCNG4RmNnxhT4B8i3zd3BvjF6CccpMA&sig2=16xX_QEFrUIDwWFLK16bnw)

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29)

But you should be aware, that hierarchical M:N relationships can get quite complex really fast!

Comment: Yes I understand this concept but not applying it to the Nested Set Model.  So that is my question, can the Nested Set Model handle this and if so how?

Comment: @swisscheese It can't in any really simple way. Perhaps you could try to save only references in the tree (IDs of items pointing to a different table which would hold the data). But I don't think the nested set model is really suitable for this.

Answer (score 4):

Thinking out loud here, but perhaps it would be helpful to view some attributes (like Red, Yellow and Green) as 'tags' instead of 'categories' and handle them with separate logic.  That would let you keep the Nested Set model and avoid unnecessary duplication. Plus, it would allow you to keep your categories simpler.

It's all in how you think about the information. Categories are just another way of representing attributes. I understand your example was just for illustrative purposes, but if you're going to categorize fruit by color, why would you not also categorize meat the same way, i.e., white meat and red meat?  Most likely you would not.  So my point is it's probably not necessary to categorize fruit by color, either.

Instead, some attributes are better represented in other ways.  In fact, in its simplest form, it could be recorded as a column in the 'food' table labeled 'color'.  Or, if it's a very common attribute and you find yourself duplicating the value significantly, it could be split off to a separate table named 'color' and mapped to each food item from a third table.  Of course, the more abstract approach would be to generalize the table as 'tags' and include each color as an individual tag that can then be mapped to any food item.  Then you can map any number of tags (colors) to any number of food items, giving you a true many-to-many relationship and freeing up your category designations to be more generalized as well.

I know there's ongoing debate about whether tags are categories or categories are tags, etc., but this appears to be one instance in which they could be complimentary and create a more abstract and robust system that's easier to manage.

Comment: I had the same thought, not sure if I have missed some of the possible consequences but kinda makes sense to think of colors as tags.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I found a better answer to this problem.

Since apple can have different color, your structure is a graph,not a tree. The nested set model is not the right structure for that.

Since you mention in a comment that you're using Mysql, a better solution is to use the Open Query Graph engine (http://openquery.com/graph/doc) which is a mysql plugin that lets you create a special table where you put the relationships, basically parentId and childId.
The magic is that you query this table with a special column latch depending of the value passed in the query will tell the OQGRAPH engine which command to execute. See the docs for details.

Comment: the link is no longer working. `web.archive.org` has [snapshot](http://web.archive.org/web/20130319105520/http://openquery.com/graph/doc) of it.