# Closure Table the best SELECT QUERY

Tags: mysql, transitive-closure-table

I am developing threaded comments system for MySQL and PHP. I chose Closure Table pattern, but I have problem. I need query (queries) to get whole tree. How to do that? I have searched a lot about this, but I can´t find nothing optimal. If you have something better for threaded comments please let me know. Tnanks for your reply.

Comment: Recursion is not well supported in MySQL.  You will have to write some code.

Comment: You can make finding an entire thread easier by storing a reference to the head (original post) with each record for a comment in that thread.  If one stores only the minimal amount of linkage between comments (the immediate parent of a reply), then clearly more work has to be done to reconstruct the thread in which a given comment occurs.  So, there are some trade-offs to consider.  Are they of interest?

Comment: One approach might be to use the nested set model. There's a sample diagram and some links on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368299/hierarchical-data-nested-set-model-mysql

Comment: I know, so what is the powerful solution for threaded comments in PHP and MYSQL?

Comment: I prefer the materialized path solution for simplicity and speed.

Answer (score 2):

If this usecase is a common one in your application, just store the root id (id of the root of the tree. this can be the id of the post to which these comments belong). Now when you need to get the whole tree of comments, you just need to do :

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE root_id = <root_id>
```

or an equivalent query for your design. If you provide your table definitions, I can help you out with specific queries.

Update:

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$sql = "SELECT A.*, GROUP_CONCAT(descendant) as descendants FROM Comments AS A INNER JOIN Paths AS B ON A.id = B.ancestor WHERE A.item = ? GROUP BY A.id";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($item));
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$adjacency_list = array(); $comments = array();
foreach($data as $row) {
    $comments[$row['id']] = $row;
    $descendants = explode(',', $row['descendants']);
    $adjacency_list[$row['id']] = $descendants;
}

echo '<UL>';
foreach($adjacency_list[$item] as $top_level_comment) {
    printTree($top_level_comment, $adjacency_list[$top_level_comment]);
}
echo '</UL>';

function printTree($node, $descendants) {
    echo '<LI>'.$node;
    if(sizeof($descendants) > 0) {
        echo '<UL>';
        foreach($descendants as $descendant) {
            $d = array();
            if(!empty($adjacency_list[$descendant])) $d = $adjacency_list[$descendant];
            printTree($descendant, $adjacency_list[$descendant]);
        }
        echo '</UL>';
    }
    echo '</LI>';
}
```

Nested Set Model, on the other hand, is not a good solution for commenting system because of the high inserts and updates. It is an efficient solution if you your data is rarely updated.

Comment: I know it. Thank you, but I don´t know how to render the whole tree wchich belongs to any post.

Comment: Once you have the adjacency list, it is a simple matter of traversing the tree. Can you provide your table schema?

Comment: Comments
[ id,  item,  author,  ip,  text,  time,  host,  vote,  vote_counter ]

- item is id of post which is commented and I want to show all comments for it

Paths
[ ancestor,  descendant,  depth ]

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT `Comments`.* FROM `Comments`
LEFT JOIN `TreePaths` ON `Comments`.`iD` = `TreePaths`.`descendant`
WHERE `TreePaths`.`ancestor` = <Root ID>
```

This will pull all the nodes for a given tree out of your closure table, but at the moment they are not ordered correctly. I'll update this post if I ever figure out the last part. Programmatically you could get the correct order with the information in the result set but I would prefer it be correct in the results.

Answer (score 1):

I came across your question because I am looking at closure tables as well. I think your problem can be solved if you follow Bill Karwin's advice on closure tables in his book "Sql anti-patterns":

> Store one row in this table for each
>   pair of nodes in the tree that shares an ancestor/descendant relationship,
>   *even if they are separated by multiple levels in the tree*.

(my emphasis)

Thus, one query on `parentId` would produce all children of the parent in one shot. (In SQL server this could be done by a recursive query).

And:

> You can improve the Closure Table to make queries for immediate
>   parent or child nodes easier. Add a TreePaths.path_length attribute
>   to the Closure Table design.

That is: store the distance between items in the closure table.

I think you'd really like his example. It's about comment threads as well.