# Handling Multi level category structure dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data

Currently working on the project related to Business listing. I need some help in handing category structure.

Using the table name Bus_CategoryTbl to maintain the categories & used fields are Cat_ID, Cat_Name, Cat_Slug, Cat_Level etc., In this, Cat_PID will have the Cat_ID of the parent category.

Here are the example records,

```
Cat_ID   Cat_name           Cat_Slug            Cat_PID
1        Web Design         web-design          0
2        PHP                php                 1
3        MYSQL              mysql               1
4        Hotels             hotels              0
5        5 Stars            5-stars             4
6        3 stars            3-stars             4
7        Le Meridian        le-meridian         5
8        St Laurn Suites    st-laurn-suites     5
9        Niraali Executive  niraali             6
```

Cat_PID value 0 indicates first level parent category.

Above is the example records, above table have 3 levels. For Ex: Hotels (Cat_ID: 4) -> 5 Stars (Cat_ID: 5) -> St Laurn Suites (Cat_ID: 8)

How the acheive the above result dynamically using PHP/MySql (Levels may increased in future)? It should not utiize more CPU time. current code was written in 3 dimensional array structure using foreach, but its little confused  taking more CPU time.

Can you someone help me in achieving this? TIA.

Comment: One way to do this would be nested sets. This question is a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368299/hierarchical-data-nested-set-model-mysql

Comment: Thanks for the info. Let me check & confirm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code

```
    function Fname($parentId=0){
    $catgArray = array();
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table Where Cat_PID=$parentId");
    $mainCatg = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    foreach($mainCatg as $mc){
    array_push($catgArray , $mc);
     $subCatg = $this->Fname($mc->Cat_ID);
                if (count($subCatg ) > 0) {
                    array_push($catgArray , $subCatg );
                }
    }
return $catgArray;
    }
```

In the Result we can check the sub category levels by using is_array() function